# PCB to schematic

Tags: pcb, schematics, reverse-engineering

Is there a software package out there that will allow you to layout a board and "populate" it and then render a schematic from that board? I have a few power supplies to fix and no documentation on their internals, this would allow me to reverse engineer and give me a good base to work from.

Comment: Most PCB design packages are intended to go from schematic to layout only. But (I hate to say it), [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/) appears to be able to work in the way that you want. You can do your editing in any of its "modes" and then switch to any other.

Comment: Dave As much as it feels like playing with Duplo, Fritzing does exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure if it can handle a complicated layout but it can export XML and Spice netlists so I should be able to import and do proper testing in Pulsonix. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you take the time to lay out the board instead of just making the schematic? You're adding the same parts and connections...

Comment: Almost the same question (with more answers): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191575/make-simple-pcb-and-export-gerber-file

Answer (score 2):

I recomend looking into CIRCAD. Seems to work for what you are looking for
http://www.holophase.com/index.html
Its a little clunky but it does push from PCB to scheamtic side with out too much issue.